# Why not change the first "to" to "of" in "assign ... to ... to ..."?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I see this sentence in a book:

> Each statement assigns the value to the right of the equal sign to the variable on the left. x = 1

I know what the **assign ... to ...** means, but there are two **to** in the sentence above. The first **to** maybe works as **of**, and the second **to** works with **assign**? Am I right. If it is, why not change the first **to** to **of**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track with parsing the sentence.  One of the **to**s is part of "assign ___ to ___":

> Each statement assigns (something) to the variable on the left.

So what is (something) here?

> the value to the right of the equal sign

This is the value *which is* to the right of the equal sign.  **to the right** means "on the right-hand side".

You cannot replace this **to** with **of**.  "of the right of the equal sign" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks. Why **of** makes no sense? Is it better change **to** to **on**? As there are two **to**s here, why doesn't this make readers mistakenly think that the first **to** is used with assgin?

Comment: **Of** does not make sense because that's not how we say it in English.  We say "He is standing *to* the right of me", not "He is standing *of* the right of me."    I don't think native speakers would find the sentence confusing, because "to the right" is such a standard phrase.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I know now.